# How can I call a method for multiple variables efficiently?

Tags: python

Here is a line of code from my program:

```
self.startcash, self.price, self.highroll, self.lowroll = self.prompt_user()
```

What you are seeing here is my attempt to get multiple variables from one method call. From my understanding of the PEP, it is unwise to put in so many variables in one line. Is there any way I can shorten these self calls/ break it down into multiple lines without calling the prompt_user method more than once?

NOTE: What Prompt_user does is that it gets input for the variables from users.

Comment: Is there any reason not to have `prompt_user` just assign these instead of return them?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which part of PEP8 were you referring to? I assume it's PEP8...

Comment: @pavel it's the one that limits the maximum number of characters in a line.

Comment: Oh yeah, but in these case you can (although it's not recommended) use `\\` line continuation to break a line into two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to make it short and more readable, then you can just use tuple indexes, but that is likely to be a less readable option. Personally, I don't think there's much wrong with how you have it right now as long you don't have it like this everywhere. But anyway, you can convert your line:

```
self.startcash, self.price, self.highroll, self.lowroll = self.prompt_user()
```

to this:

```
output = self.prompt_user()

self.startcash = output[0]
self.price = output[1]
self.highroll = output[2]
self.lowroll = output[3]
```

Comment: To think a simple list can solve all of my problems that I had trying to solve this since yesterday

Comment: You're welcome, but here `output` is not a list, but a tuple.

Comment: Yeah right, my bad. Now can I change all values in the output tuple into absolute values? Something like abs(output) maybe? [I know that is totally wrong]

Comment: Sure, just do `abs(output[1])` etc.

Comment: Do I have to do abs(--snip--) for every variable or does a better way exist? It's kinda tedious, not to mention it will be trouble if I want to expand my program further

Comment: @penjelmaankatak You can use a list comprehension. `output = [abs(val) for val in output]`. This will make output into a list, but that doesn't matter for your case. You can make it into a tuple aswell

Comment: @Evan Something like this? : `output = [abs(val) for val in self.prompt_user()]`

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to set them all to `None` (or some default value) in `__init__`

```
self.startcash = self.price = self.highroll = self.lowroll = None  # can make multiple lines
```

And then in your `prompt_user` function, you can set the variables using `self`, because you are using OOP

```
def prompt_user(self):
    self.startcast = input('startcash: ')
    self.price = input('price: ')
    self.highroll = input('highroll: ')
    self.lowroll = input('lowroll: ')
```